# Stop listening to event from inside event listener

Tags: events, dart

I want to listen to an event stream, then conditionally stop listening based on the received event.

In short, I'd like to use:

```
var subscription = stream.listen((event) {
    if (f(event)) {
        doStuff();
        subscription.cancel();
    } else {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
});
```

This obviously doesn't work; `subscription` doesn't exist until the listener has been created, resulting in an error.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just declare the subscription before subscribing to the stream:

```dart
var subscription;
subscription = stream.listen((event) {
  if (f(event)) {
    doStuff();
    subscription.cancel();
  } else {
    doOtherStuff();
  }
});
```

Comment: I feel silly now. I thought for some reason that dart had capture-by-value rather than capture-by-name (with something interesting going on with loops).

Answer (score 8):

Divide and conquer.

First, let's consider the `if (f(event))` part. That takes only the first item that matches the predicate and performs an operation. There are two ways of doing this:

```dart
stream.where((event) => f(event)).take(1).listen((event) => doStuff());
```

That's the generic way of doing things, and it means we use the Stream interface all through. Another way of doing it, which might avoid a few addition and comparison operations, requires switching to the Future interface:

```dart
stream.firstWhere((event) => f(event)).then((event) => doStuff());
```

That only handles the first part of the condition. What about the second part? We want to grab everything until the condition holds true, so we'll use `takeWhile`:

```dart
stream.takeWhile((event) => !f(event)).listen((event) => doOtherStuff());
```

And Bob's your uncle.

If the code is essentially the same for both listeners, you can separate it out into another function, of course.